# Stop a service before installation

Tags: visual-studio, windows-services, setup-project

I wrote an application that installs using the Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project.  As part of its installation, my application installs and starts a Windows Service.  No problems there.

When I release a new version of the application, the installer overwrites the contents of the application folder.  Unfortunately, it cannot overwrite the service as it is already running.

How can I stop the service before the MSI starts copying files?  I'm considering a custom bootstrapper (installer prerequisit) that doesn't install, but removes the service.  Or can I use Orca to add an action before installation?  Or do you know another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this is done through [service control operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371634%28VS.85%29.aspx). Basically, you need the Stop and Delete flags set for uninstall.

Another approach would be to use [ServiceInstaller.Uninstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.uninstall.aspx) in a custom action to stop and remove the service.

If you want to avoid the files in use dialog, you can try this approach:
[Problem stopping Windows Service from Installer Class. Events fire too late](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292459/problem-stopping-windows-service-from-installer-class-events-fire-too-late)

Comment: Thanks!  The service control operations looks like what I'm after.  I think upgrading to WiX is going to save me a lot of headaches in future.  Visual Studio's setup project is just too limited, especially for determining the action sequence.